# How to put image in input type submit

Tags: html

I want to put image as value in input type=submit.
I tried that:

```
    <input type="submit"  value="<img src='25.gif'/>"/>
```

But it does not work, i don't know why.
Can you help me ?

NOT input type="image" that i know.

Comment: are you trying to submit an image in your form? or are you trying to display an image instead of the `submit` button? please clarify.  Also, please refer to our [ask] for hints on how to write a good question.  Good questions tend to receive faster, better answers from the community

Comment: Yes I want to display image instead of the submit button.

Answer (score 3):

```css
 .submit{
  background-image: url(https://wallscover.com/images/cool-6.jpg);
  min-width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position:center;
 }
```

```html
<input type="submit" class="submit" value=""/>
```

**Update**
What you need can be achieved using a div as the button, and setting an image to the div. When user clicks the divs you call the click of the submit ( or alternatively you can submit from js )

```css
#submit-button{
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px lightgray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#submit-button:hover{
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px lightgray;
}

img{
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="submit-button" onclick="document.getElementById('submit-btn').click()">
  <img src="https://wallscover.com/images/cool-6.jpg" width="50">
  <input type="submit" style="display:none" id="submit-btn" />
</div>
```

Comment: <input type="submit"  value="send"/> I want to replace that "send" by an image not to have background. I don't know if it's possible. Is it ?

Comment: Ahhh sure it is

Comment: But that will need some javascript

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I believe you want to make background image:

https://jsfiddle.net/nfwaqpz3/2/

HTML

```
<input type="submit" value="Button" id="foo" />
```

CSS

```
#foo {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background: url('https://sciencetrends-techmakaillc.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/DhLkp-450x304.jpg'); 
}
```